# How to dynamic bind Unicode to page title

Tags: unicode, durandal

I use `Durandal` for my website (http://cuoidiku.com/).

It's contain alot of funny story in homepage, when I click to title of story, I want to bind this content to `document.title`. It works, but the `unicode` show not correct. A lot of special symbol there (such as `v&#224`...).

I google and found some suggestion is adding `\u` before specical symbol, But in my case, this title from database, and I cannot detect where specical symbol is?

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Can you give an example of the string that you are getting from the database with the unicode?

Comment: you can go to my site `http://cuoidiku.com/` and click in any title has special charactes. Sory because I don't know how to copy it to show here.

Comment: I don't see the issue on your site.  I don't know the language that is used.  My initial thought is that you should be able to handle with with JavaScript and it is not a durandaljs issue.